# How to check for changes on remote (origin) Git repository

Tags: git

What are the Git commands to do the following workflow?

**Scenario**

I cloned from a repository and did some commits of my own to my local repository. In the meantime, my colleagues made commits to the remote repository. Now, I want to:

1. Check whether there are any new
   commits from other people on the
   remote repository, i.e. `origin`?
2. Say there were three new commits on the
   remote repository since my last
   pull, I would like to diff the
   remote repository's commits, i.e.
   `HEAD~3` with `HEAD~2`, `HEAD~2` with
   `HEAD~1` and `HEAD~1` with `HEAD`.
3. After knowing what changed remotely,
   I want to get the latest commits
   from the others.

**My findings so far**

For step 2: I know the caret notation `HEAD^`, `HEAD^^` etc. and the tilde notation `HEAD~2`, `HEAD~3`, etc.

For step 3: That is, I guess, just a `git pull`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if pull needed in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Comment: @Daniele that answer you are linking to is superb and even comes with a customizable bash script. +1

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You could `git fetch origin` to update the remote branch in your repository to point to the latest version. For a diff against the remote:

```
git diff origin/master
```

Yes, you can use caret notation as well.

If you want to accept the remote changes:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: The diff looks reversed. I find it easier to use `git diff HEAD origin/master` so the diff shows what will be applied if I accept the remote changes.

Comment: "git fetch origin" and "git show-branch *master" were useful to me.

Answer (score 177):

```
git remote update && git status
```

Found this on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/201514) to [Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed/)

> `git remote update` to bring your remote refs up to date. Then you can
>   do one of several things, such as:
>
> 1. `git status -uno` will tell you whether the branch you are tracking is ahead, behind or has diverged. If it says nothing, the local and
>      remote are the same.
> 2. `git show-branch *master` will show you the commits in all of the branches whose names end in master (eg master and origin/master).
>
> If you use `-v` with `git remote update` you can see which branches
>   got updated, so you don't really need any further commands.

Comment: Not enough. I have to do a `git pull <remote> <branch>` afterwards as soon as I need to push, because the tip of my local branch was behind the remote counterpart.

Comment: @Overdrivr the question asks for a way to check changes before getting the commits to the local branch. so, yes, you have to update your local branch after checking for changes.

Comment: Is this for remote being origin or upstream ?

Comment: That -v option doesn't work. For `git remote update -v` I got `error: unknown switch \`v'`

Comment: @vikramvi `git remote update` will update all the remotes. `git status` will check for changes in this branch to the configured remote. You could use `git remote -v` to see all the configured remotes and `git branch -vv` to see which remote this branch is tracking

Comment: @Shad you should do `git remote -v update` not `git remote update -v`

Answer (score 39):

A good way to have a synthetic view of what's going on "origin" is:

```
git remote show origin
```

Comment: But that command doesn't show me how many commits there have been on "origin" since my last pull, does it? The way I understood it "git remote show origin" is a local operation and does not go over the network to fetch information.

Comment: The output ***doesn't contain any*** information about the *content* of the remote.

Comment: @Lernkurve The remote repository is now queried by default, but there is a switch (`-n`) for using the remote's cached status: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emshowem

Answer (score 35):

I just use

```
git remote update
git status
```

The latter then reports how many commits behind my local is (if any).

Then

```
git pull origin master
```

to bring my local up to date :)

Answer (score 25):

My regular question is rather "anything new or changed in repo" so *whatchanged* comes handy. Found it [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/30/finding-what-has-been-changed.html).

```
git whatchanged origin/master -n 1
```

Answer (score 11):

**One potential solution**

Thanks to [Alan Haggai Alavi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514270/how-to-check-for-changes-on-remote-origin-git-repository/2514299#2514299) I came up with the following potential workflow:

Step 1:

```
git fetch origin
```

Step 2:

```
git checkout -b localTempOfOriginMaster origin/master
git difftool HEAD~3 HEAD~2
git difftool HEAD~2 HEAD~1
git difftool HEAD~1 HEAD~0
```

Step 3:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D localTempOfOriginMaster
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: Why do you need to make a temporary branch for diff between revisions of the remote? you can just `git diff origing/master^ origing/master^^`

Comment: @Pablo Marin-Garcia: No, `git diff origin/master^ origin/master^^`

Answer (score 4):

`git status` does not always show the difference between master and origin/master even after a fetch.

If you want the combination `git fetch origin && git status` to work, you need to specify the tracking information between the local branch and origin:

```
# git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <branch>
```

For the *master* branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

Comment: Might still specify how to do a diff here.

Answer (score 2):

I simply use

```
git fetch origin
```

to fetch the remote changes, and then I view both local and pending remote commits (and their associated changes) with the nice [gitk tool](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) involving the `--all` argument like:

```
gitk --all
```

Comment: The question specified a git command. There are many git tools that can be used to check a remote branch status. Promoting a particular one is not very helpful. I realize this is a tool documented in the official git documentation, but it is still independently maintained, hence my disagreement.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1), only checking for, but not fetching/pulling any changes from remote yet, you could use:

`git fetch -j 4 --dry-run --porcelain | head -n 1`

This will only look for and show any new remote commits, running on 4 parallel jobs (faster) and limiting the result to only the first line/commit.

It is easily adapted to your needs and can be used in scripts due to the simple format, helping you to quickly check, if any changes are present, which can be processed further as required.

To get all new available commits, leave the `head` part beginning from the pipe symbol.

In order to actually download them, also remove `--dry-run` from the command.

I like to do a separate `fetch` and then `git merge --progress --strategy-option=patience` instead of `git pull`, to have better control and more information about what will happen, when merging the lokal worktree with remote changes.

EDIT:
I also commonly use `-p` (prune) with fetch, so dangling remote-tracking references to remotely non-existent branches get removed locally.