# Check if pull needed in Git

Tags: git, bash, shell

How do I check whether the remote repository has changed and I need to pull?

Now I use this simple script:

```
git pull --dry-run | grep -q -v 'Already up-to-date.' && changed=1
```

But it is rather heavy.

Is there a better way? The ideal solution would check all the remote branches, and return names of the changed branches and the number of new commits in each one.

Comment: Please note: "git pull --dry-run" does not work as probably expected.
It seems, that git pull passes unknown options directly to git fetch. The result is that of a normal git pull.

Comment: "pull" is just a short way to do "fetch" and "merge" at once, if you need to check the remote repo status you are really simulating a "fetch". So `git fetch -v --dry-run` is what you need.

Comment: I tried the solution proposed by OP, and it does returned nothing. Probably not the best approach?

Comment: I don't understand if the original question was about a shell script (having something clean while writing a script) or having something simple during everyday shell usage. Can you specify it in the question?

Comment: You may be interested in Git's new feature: [autostash](https://cscheng.info/2017/01/26/git-tip-autostash-with-git-pull-rebase.html).

Answer (score 1035, accepted):

First use [`git remote update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), to bring your remote refs up to date. Then you can do one of several things, such as:

1. `git status -uno` will tell you whether the branch you are tracking is ahead, behind or has diverged. If it says nothing, the local and remote are the same.
2. `git show-branch *master` will show you the commits in all of the branches whose names end in 'master' (eg *master* and *origin/master*).

If you use `-v` with `git remote update` (`git remote -v update`) you can see which branches got updated, so you don't really need any further commands.

However, it looks like you want to do this in a script or program and end up with a true/false value. If so, there are ways to check the relationship between your current *HEAD* commit and the head of the branch you're tracking, although since there are four possible outcomes you can't reduce it to a yes/no answer. However, if you're prepared to do a `pull --rebase` then you can treat "local is behind" and "local has diverged" as "need to pull", and the other two ("local is ahead" and "same") as "don't need to pull".

You can get the commit id of any ref using `git rev-parse <ref>`, so you can do this for *master* and *origin/master* and compare them. If they're equal, the branches are the same. If they're unequal, you want to know which is ahead of the other. Using `git merge-base master origin/master` will tell you the common ancestor of both branches, and if they haven't diverged this will be the same as one or the other. If you get three different ids, the branches have diverged.

To do this properly, eg in a script, you need to be able to refer to the current branch, and the remote branch it's tracking. The bash prompt-setting function in `/etc/bash_completion.d` has some useful code for getting branch names. However, you probably don't actually need to get the names. Git has some neat shorthands for referring to branches and commits (as documented in `git rev-parse --help`). In particular, you can use `@` for the current branch (assuming you're not in a detached-head state) and `@{u}` for its upstream branch (eg `origin/master`). So `git merge-base @ @{u}` will return the (hash of the) commit at which the current branch and its upstream diverge and `git rev-parse @` and `git rev-parse @{u}` will give you the hashes of the two tips. This can be summarized in the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'}
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$UPSTREAM")
BASE=$(git merge-base @ "$UPSTREAM")

if [ $LOCAL = $REMOTE ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
elif [ $LOCAL = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to pull"
elif [ $REMOTE = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to push"
else
    echo "Diverged"
fi
```

*Note:* older versions of git didn't allow `@` on its own, so you may have to use `@{0}` instead.

The line `UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'}` allows you optionally to pass an upstream branch explicitly, in case you want to check against a different remote branch than the one configured for the current branch. This would typically be of the form *remotename/branchname*. If no parameter is given, the value defaults to `@{u}`.

The script assumes that you've done a `git fetch` or `git remote update` first, to bring the tracking branches up to date. I didn't build this into the script because it's more flexible to be able to do the fetching and the comparing as separate operations, for example if you want to compare without fetching because you already fetched recently.

Comment: @takeshin I guess you could combine git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master as suggested by @brool with git rev-list --max-count=1 origin/master. If they return the same hash, the remote branch hasn't changed since you last updated your remote refs (with pull, fetch, remote update, etc.) This would have the advantage that you wouldn't have to pull down the content of all the commits right away, but could leave that for a more convenient time. However, since remote update is non-destructive, you might as well do it anyway.

Comment: You could also try `git status -s -u no`, which gives a shorter output than `git status -u no`.

Comment: This will not work if you are not on the local tracking branch. See my answer for a more general solution.

Comment: @Nocturne Your answer isn't more general, because it still requires knowledge of the effective upstream branch to be hard-coded into the command (origin/master in your example). The feature branch may well be forked from a different upstream branch (eg develop if you're using git-flow). It's true that you've used HEAD rather than master, but using git merge-base HEAD origin/master would still be much superior for scripting purposes to using git log.

Also, my final paragraph addresses the need for generality, which is actually much more complex than just substituting HEAD for master.

Comment: Stupid question, but could someone give a full example of the command using `-v`? The "if you use `-v` with ..." statement is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @mhulse, `git remote -v update`. Look at the output of `git remote --help` for a fuller explanation.

Comment: When I make changes to my local branch and then use `git status -uno`, it doesn't return any information about the fact that the branch I'm tracking is now behind.

Comment: @Cerran, It should say something like, "Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit". If not, then maybe you don't have an upstream branch set, or you didn't commit your changes yet.

Comment: your script is nice, but it doesn't work for me: I need to specify HEAD to make it work; otherwise I get "ambiguous argument '@' errors. My commands: git rev-parse HEAD, git rev-parse HEAD@{u} and git merge-base HEAD HEAD@{u}.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Good point. The more explicit syntax is needed with older versions of git. I experimented with the various systems I have and found that `@{u}` works with git 1.8.3.2 but `@` doesn't. However `@` works with `1.8.5.4`. Moral of the story: git keeps improving and it's worth having the most recent version you can.

Comment: A specifier is now required for @. You can use @{0} instead of @.

Comment: @BenDavis: `git rev-parse --help` says `@ alone is a shortcut for HEAD`. I'm using git version `2.1.1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this script in cron job to automate merge of different repositories.

Comment: Is your code really correct? I tried it but even although there's no need to pull it's still passing through the path of `$LOCAL = $BASE`. Is this really the check I should make to see if a pull is needed?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves, So the test `$LOCAL = $REMOTE` failed. Are you sure you don't need to pull? Check what `git status` says. Also, did you do `git remote update` first, as explained at the top of the post? If your remote was 'rewound' (eg with a non-ff push) since you last did `fetch` or `remote update` then local and remote could be the same but git has no way of knowing that.

Comment: @NeilMayhew I did `git fetch`, not `git remote update`. The instruction was to run one of these commands, not both of them. So you are saying I need to run `git remote update` AND `git fetch`?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves, no, you don't need to run both. `git fetch` and `git remote update` are almost the same, but not quite. `remote update` looks at all remotes whereas `fetch` looks at only one of them. By default, `fetch` uses the one for the current branch, or `origin` if the current branch doesn't have a remote. But you do need to have done one of these, *since* the last time someone pushed or rewound the remote branch.

Comment: This only seems to work for the default origin. How can I check if a pull is needed from a non-default origin? What is the meaning of the @ @{u} notations?

Comment: Answering my own question: @=HEAD and @{u}=@{upstream} and to check non-standard remotes, simply replace "@{u}" with "remotes/REMOTE/master". Implemented here: https://github.com/KIAaze/bin_and_dotfiles_public/blob/6d56f7e82e055841b9f65429f5f5fb76c4de921e/bins/public_bin/gitcheck.sh (cf also Bruno Adelé's answer for a much more advanced script).

Comment: @KIAaze, the use of `@` and `@{u}` works for any remote, so it's not necessary to use `remotes/REMOTE/master` or anything similar. Git already knows which branch and remote the current branch pulls from, and the `@{u}` notation allows you to take advantage of this. In other words, the script I've given works with any remote.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I sometimes pull from a different location, which is not set as default upstream (In fact that is the main one I usually want to check before I pull from it. My branch is always master, but remote is not always branch.master.remote). Anyway, you helped me solve my problem and I learned a lot more about git revspecs and other stuff on the way. :)

Comment: @KIAaze, Ah, I understand now. I'll modify the script to allow the upstream branch to be specified as an optional command-line parameter, defaulting to `@{u}`. Thanks for highlighting this additional use-case.

Comment: if i pass in argument to this script, it will fail

Comment: @JamesTan It depends what argument you pass in. You need to give it the name of another branch, typically a remote-tracking branch like `origin/master`.

Answer (score 151):

### If you have an upstream branch

```
git fetch <remote>
git status
```

### If you don't have an upstream branch

Compare the two branches:

```
git fetch <remote>
git log <local_branch_name>..<remote_branch_name> --oneline
```

For example:

```
git fetch origin

# See if there are any incoming changes
git log HEAD..origin/master --oneline
```

(I'm assuming `origin/master` is your remote tracking branch)

If any commits are listed in the output above, then you have incoming changes -- you need to merge.  If no commits are listed by `git log` then there is nothing to merge.

Note that this will work even if you are on a feature branch -- that does not have a tracking remote, since if explicitly refers to `origin/master` instead of implicitly using the *upstream branch* remembered by Git.

Comment: Even a shorter notation `git fetch; git log HEAD.. --oneline` can be used if there's a default remote branch for local one.

Comment: @philpirozhkov If you have a default remote branch, a simple "git status" should do I think. My answer was a generic one for any two branches, where one may or may not be tracking the other.

Comment: `git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count` will give you the total number of "different" commits between the two.

Comment: short and simple. My favorite solution that just shows the new commits (thumbs up twice)

Comment: How can I use this in a (Ubuntu) batch file, so that I can run other commands just in the case this command shows that a pull is needed?

Comment: This doesn't work if your upstream isn't `origin/master`. If you're using *git flow* it will be `origin/develop`, for example, and if you have multiple remotes then the remote for your upstream branch may not be called `origin`. I often work on multiple development machines (because I'm doing cross-platform development) and I want to test my changes on all platforms before pushing upstream. The easiest way to do this is to add each machine as a remote to the others, and push and pull between them.

Comment: Is there a more general solution for whatever the current branch is?

Comment: Very useful shortcut from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251377/4114447 :
If you want to compare your branch with the appropriate remote tracking branch (and not just master), you can use `git log HEAD..@{u} --oneline`
See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem

Comment: A side note of @JakeBerger comment, you first have to ```git fetch``` to receive the latest changes at remote.

Answer (score 108):

If this is for a script, you can use:

```
git fetch
$(git rev-parse HEAD) == $(git rev-parse @{u})
```

(Note: the benefit of this vs. previous answers is that you don't need a separate command to get the current branch name. "HEAD" and "@{u}" (the current branch's upstream) take care of it. See "git rev-parse --help" for more details.)

Comment: I discovered @{u} independently and had updated my answer before I saw yours.

Comment: Will `git rev-parse @{u}` actually show the latest commit without a `git fetch`?

Comment: This was the ticket!  Although, your logic is using `==` which means "if there are NO changes from upstream".  I used `!=` to check for "if there ARE changes from upstream" for my application.  Don't forget to `git fetch` first!

Comment: I added git fetch, because it really is necessary to answer the original question. `@` is short for `HEAD` btw.

Comment: Windows users will need single quotes around the `@{u}` e.g.`git rev-parse '@{u}'`

Answer (score 48):

Here's a Bash one-liner that compares the current branch's HEAD commit hash against its remote upstream branch, no heavy `git fetch` or `git pull --dry-run` operations required:

```
[ $(git rev-parse HEAD) = $(git ls-remote $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} | \
sed 's/\// /g') | cut -f1) ] && echo up to date || echo not up to date
```

Here's how this somewhat dense line is broken down:

- Commands are grouped and nested using `$(x)` Bash [command-substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax.
- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u}` returns an abbreviated upstream ref (e.g. `origin/master`), which is then converted into space-separated fields by the piped `sed` command, e.g. `origin master`.
- This string is fed into `git ls-remote` which returns the head commit of the remote branch. This command will communicate with the remote repository. The piped `cut` command extracts just the first field (the commit hash), removing the tab-separated reference string.
- `git rev-parse HEAD` returns the local commit hash.
- The Bash syntax `[ a = b ] && x || y` completes the one-liner: this is a Bash [string-comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#SCOMPARISON1) `=` within a test construct `[ test ]`, followed by and-list and or-list constructs `&& true || false`.

Comment: I would *not* use /g on the sed if you use slashes in the branch names.  That is "sed 's/\// /" only.

Comment: @wjordan Your solution fails when the remote repository isn't reachable (or under maintenance) and will trigger "up to date"

Comment: @frame in almost all use-cases that would be preferable outcome. If the remote is currently unreachable, your local would semantically be up to date as of the last time you ran the script.

Answer (score 44):

The command

```
git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master
```

will list the current head on the remote -- you can compare it to a previous value or see if you have the SHA in your local repo.

Comment: Any sample script to compare these values?

Comment: `git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count` will give you the total number of "different" commits between the two.

Comment: @jberger to clarify, that will only show the number of commits you're behind (not ahead and behind) and it only works if you `git fetch` or `git remote update` first. `git status` also shows a count, btw.

Comment: @Dennis I thought `..` is "commits in origin/master, subtracting HEAD" (i.e. number of commits behind). Whereas, `...` is the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (i.e. ahead and behind)

Comment: @jberger Thanks for the tip, but I'm not sure how to use it. Is this right? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17192101/242933

Comment: Excellent. As far as I can tell, this is the only solution that actually checks the origin for updates but doesn't implicitly do a `fetch`.

Answer (score 23):

I suggest you go see the script https://github.com/badele/gitcheck. I have coded this script for check in one pass all your Git repositories, and it shows who has not committed and who has not pushed/pulled.

Here a sample result:

[image]

Comment: neat, thinking about rewriting it in pure shell

Comment: Now, you can also use gitcheck directly from an docker container (with your files in your host) For more information see the gitcheck github project

Comment: A similar tool in bash [git-multi-repo-tooling](https://github.com/gregbugaj/git-multi-repo-tooling) .  `git mrepo -c` this will display all pending commits.

Answer (score 23):

The below script works perfectly.

```
changed=0
git remote update && git status -uno | grep -q 'Your branch is behind' && changed=1
if [ $changed = 1 ]; then
    git pull
    echo "Updated successfully";
else
    echo "Up-to-date"
fi
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu with .sh scripts and works with files changed (checks if pull is possible/needed instead of unclean state)

Answer (score 16):

I just want to post this as an actual post as it is easy to miss this in the comments.

The correct and best answer for this question was given by @Jake Berger, Thank you very much dude, everyone need this and everyone misses this in the comments.
So for everyone struggling with this here is the correct answer, just use the output of this command to know if you need to do a git pull. if the output is 0 then obviously there is nothing to update.

@stackoverflow, give this guy a bells.
Thanks @ Jake Berger

```sh
# will give you the total number of "different" commits between the two
# Jake Berger Feb 5 '13 at 19:23
git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count
```

Comment: Thanks for making it pretty Arnaud :)

Comment: Does this need a `fetch` to work as expected, or does the reference to `origin/master` mean git will query the remote without fetching anything locally?

Comment: @NickChammas this command is local, so it is useful **after** `fetch` and **before** `pull/merge/reset`

Answer (score 14):

I think the best way to do this would be:

```
git diff remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Assuming that you have the this refspec registered. You should if you have cloned the repository, otherwise (i.e., if the repo was created de novo locally, and pushed to the remote), you need to add the refspec explicitly.

Answer (score 12):

I based this solution on the comments of @jberger.

```
if git checkout master &&
    git fetch origin master &&
    [ `git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count` != 0 ] &&
    git merge origin/master
then
    echo 'Updated!'
else
    echo 'Not updated.'
fi
```

Comment: referring to your previous [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed/3258271?noredirect=1#comment3393932_3258271), at this point in time I cannot give you a definite answer. At the time I made those comments, I was diving into the depths of git and particularly remotes and diffs. It has been a few months since then and a lot of that knowledge is buried inside my brain. ;) If you're looking for the number of 'different' commits between the two, then `...` seems to be a valid part of your solution.

Answer (score 12):

There are many very feature rich and ingenious answers already. To provide some contrast, I could make do with a very simple line.

```
# Check return value to see if there are incoming updates.
if ! git diff --quiet remotes/origin/HEAD; then
 # pull or whatever you want to do
fi
```

Comment: Original answer was lacking '!' in the if. The return value from git diff is zero, when there are no changes.

Comment: IMO best solution out there, altough I need to substitute "remotes/origin/HEAD" with "origin/master" or other revision

Answer (score 7):

If you run this script, it will test if the current branch need a `git pull`:

```
#!/bin/bash

git fetch -v --dry-run 2>&1 |
    grep -qE "\[up\s+to\s+date\]\s+$(
        git branch 2>/dev/null |
           sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p' |
                sed -r 's:(\+|\*|\$):\\\1:g'
    )\s+" || {
        echo >&2 "Current branch need a 'git pull' before commit"
        exit 1
}
```

It's very convenient to put it as a Git hook pre-commit to avoid

```
Merge branch 'foobar' of url:/path/to/git/foobar into foobar
```

when you `commit` before `pulling`.

To use this code as a hook, simply copy/paste the script in

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit
```

and

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Answer (score 6):

Run `git fetch (remote)` to update your remote refs, it'll show you what's new. Then, when you checkout your local branch, it will show you whether it's behind upstream.

Comment: I think he already has the local branch checked out, so he needs something else to show whether it's behind etc. He can do this with git status.

Comment: True, after you've fetched remotes, `git status` will show that as well.

Comment: That's something in the mood `git pull --dry-run` does, but I think it is to heavy for a cron script run each minute.

Comment: @takeshin: You can't check remote repositories without going on the network. If there isn't anything new `fetch`'s not going to do much beyond than checking status. If you need a very fast and lightweight reaction on remote updates, you might want to look into hooking some kind of notifications to the remote repository.

Comment: @takeshin: if you're wanting to check the remote repo every minute I think you've missed the point of DVCS. The whole idea is to be able to develop independently for a while, and then put it all together smoothly later. It's not like cvs, svn, p4 etc. where you always have to be working on top of whatever is the latest in the repository. If you really need something that somebody else is working on, then you should use a different communication mechanism, such as email, to tell you when it's ready to pull.

Comment: @takeshin: As @che says, use the post-receive hook on the remote repo to call contrib/hooks/post-receive-email and configure this to send to a mailing list for the repo. Developers who use the remote repo can then subscribe to this list.

Answer (score 6):

I would do the way suggested by brool. The following one-line script takes the SHA1 of your last commited version and compares it to the one of the remote origin, and pull changes only if they differ.
And it's even more light-weight of the solutions based on `git pull` or `git fetch`.

```
[ `git log --pretty=%H ...refs/heads/master^` != `git ls-remote origin
-h refs/heads/master |cut -f1` ] && git pull
```

Comment: This command fails, if the git repository is cloned with "--depth 1" (to limit download size). Do you know, if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: The git log this is returning many lines, and giving a error "bash: [: too many arguments"
I'd switch to `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`

Comment: This is a simple string comparison done by bash. If something fails I would suggest you to check your syntax (i.e. you're typing it wrong).

First run

`git log --pretty=%H ...refs/heads/master^`

to get the SHA1 of your last commited version, and then run

`git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master |cut -f1`

to get the SHA1 of the remote origin.

These two are git commands and have nothing to do with bash. What bash does inside the square brackets is to compare the output from the first command with the second one, and if they are equal it returns true and runs `git pull`.

Comment: "and if they are equal it returns true and runs `git pull`". I know I'm being nitpicky, but just to save someone confusion, that should be "and if they **not** equal". Also, for whatever reason, the first git command does not work for me. (I'm on git `2.4.1`.) So I'm just using `git log --pretty=%H master | head -n1` instead. But I'm not sure if that's exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

All such complex sugestions while the solution is so short and easy:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH="<your branch name>"
LAST_UPDATE=`git show --no-notes --format=format:"%H" $BRANCH | head -n 1`
LAST_COMMIT=`git show --no-notes --format=format:"%H" origin/$BRANCH | head -n 1`

git remote update
if [ $LAST_COMMIT != $LAST_UPDATE ]; then
        echo "Updating your branch $BRANCH"
        git pull --no-edit
else
        echo "No updates available"
fi
```

Comment: LAST_COMMIT and LAST_UPDATE are always equal even if there are changes

Comment: This solution is good and simple, put needs to have `git remote update` executed before your code, to get latest origin commit info

Comment: Should `git remote update` not append before `git show` commands ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version of a Bash script that checks all repositories in a predefined folder:

https://gist.github.com/henryiii/5841984

It can differentiate between common situations, like pull needed and push needed, and it is multithreaded, so the fetch happens all at once. It has several commands, like pull and status.

Put a symlink (or the script) in a folder in your path, then it works as `git all status` (, etc.). It only supports origin/master, but it can be edited or combined with another method.

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner works for me in zsh (from @Stephen Haberman's answer)

```
git fetch; [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) = $(git rev-parse @{u}) ] \
    && echo "Up to date" || echo "Not up to date"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-remote | cut -f1 | git cat-file --batch-check >&-
```

will list everything referenced in any remote that isn't in your repo.  To catch remote ref changes to things you already had (e.g. resets to previous commits) takes a little more:

```
git pack-refs --all
mine=`mktemp`
sed '/^#/d;/^^/{G;s/.\(.*\)\n.* \(.*\)/\1 \2^{}/;};h' .git/packed-refs | sort -k2 >$mine
for r in `git remote`; do 
    echo Checking $r ...
    git ls-remote $r | sort -k2 | diff -b - $mine | grep ^\<
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a version of a script based on Stephen Haberman's answer:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    gitbin="git -C $1"
else
    gitbin="git"
fi

# Fetches from all the remotes, although --all can be replaced with origin
$gitbin fetch --all
if [ $($gitbin rev-parse HEAD) != $($gitbin rev-parse @{u}) ]; then
    $gitbin rebase @{u} --preserve-merges
fi
```

Assuming this script is called `git-fetch-and-rebase`, it can be invoked with an optional argument `directory name` of the local Git repository to perform operation on. If the script is called with no arguments, it assumes the current directory to be part of the Git repository.

Examples:

```
# Operates on /abc/def/my-git-repo-dir
git-fetch-and-rebase /abc/def/my-git-repo-dir

# Operates on the Git repository which the current working directory is part of
git-fetch-and-rebase
```

It is available [here](https://github.com/Tuxdude/git-scripts/blob/master/git-fetch-and-rebase) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this, if you want to add task as crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/path/to/root"
lock=/tmp/update.lock
msglog="/var/log/update.log"

log()
{
        echo "$(date) ${1:-missing}" >> $msglog
}

if [ -f $lock ]; then
        log "Already run, exiting..."
else
        > $lock
        git -C ~/$dir remote update &> /dev/null
        checkgit=`git -C ~/$dir status`
        if [[ ! "$checkgit" =~ "Your branch is up-to-date" ]]; then
                log "-------------- Update ---------------"
                git -C ~/$dir pull &>> $msglog
                log "-------------------------------------"
        fi
        rm $lock

fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Neils answer helped me so much here is a Python translation with no dependencies:

```
import os
import logging
import subprocess

def check_for_updates(directory:str) -> None:
    """Check git repo state in respect to remote"""
    git_cmd = lambda cmd: subprocess.run(
        ["git"] + cmd,
        cwd=directory,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        check=True,
        universal_newlines=True).stdout.rstrip("\n")

    origin = git_cmd(["config", "--get", "remote.origin.url"])
    logging.debug("Git repo origin: %r", origin)
    for line in git_cmd(["fetch"]):
        logging.debug(line)
    local_sha = git_cmd(["rev-parse", "@"])
    remote_sha = git_cmd(["rev-parse", "@{u}"])
    base_sha = git_cmd(["merge-base", "@", "@{u}"])
    if local_sha == remote_sha:
        logging.info("Repo is up to date")
    elif local_sha == base_sha:
        logging.info("You need to pull")
    elif remote_sha == base_sha:
        logging.info("You need to push")
    else:
        logging.info("Diverged")

check_for_updates(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

hth

Answer (score 1):

To automate `git pull` on a desired branch:
Use like: `./pull.sh "origin/main"`

<sub>pull.sh</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'}
DIFFCOMM=$(git fetch origin --quiet; git rev-list HEAD..."$UPSTREAM" --count)
if [ "$DIFFCOMM" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Pulling $UPSTREAM";
  git pull;
else
  echo "Up-to-date";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master
```

given by brool is the *lightest* way to just *check* if something at all has changed in the remote.

Starting from the local head:

```
$ git log -1 --oneline @
9e1ff307c779 (HEAD -> master, tag: v5.15-rc4, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Linux 5.15-rc4
```

I see that my pulled origin is up to date at that tag. `git status` says so too. But that is only the local up to date, the (fast-forward) merge after a fetch.

To check if the remote HEAD went somewhere, and also master, and maybe some new tags:

```
$ git ls-remote origin HEAD master --tags 'v5.1[56]-rc[345]*'

84b3e42564accd94c2680e3ba42717c32c8b5fc4        HEAD
84b3e42564accd94c2680e3ba42717c32c8b5fc4        refs/heads/master
71a6dc2a869beafceef1ce46a9ebefd52288f1d7        refs/tags/v5.15-rc3
5816b3e6577eaa676ceb00a848f0fd65fe2adc29        refs/tags/v5.15-rc3^{}
f3cee05630e772378957a74a209aad059714cbd2        refs/tags/v5.15-rc4
9e1ff307c779ce1f0f810c7ecce3d95bbae40896        refs/tags/v5.15-rc4^{}
```

HEAD is still on the same branch, but not the same commit anymore. That local `@` commit stays with the v5.15-rc4 tag. This is about the same info as on top of the **summary** sheet on kernel.org git:

```
Branch: master <commit message> <author> age: 2 hours
```

Only that `ls-remote` collects less information - but then again only me I know that I am on `9e1ff...` aka v5.15-rc4.

Instead of naming refs (HEAD, master) or tags one can also get a list of heads or branches from any repo:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git 

af06aff2a0007976513134dfe993d55992dd866a        refs/heads/akpm
20bcee8e95f783c11a7bea1b6a40c70a37873e0a        refs/heads/akpm-base
a25006a77348ba06c7bc96520d331cd9dd370715        refs/heads/master
4d5a088c93cea1c821d02a2217c592391d9682e2        refs/heads/pending-fixes
4de593fb965fc2bd11a0b767e0c65ff43540a6e4        refs/heads/stable
```

Here a URL replaces "origin".

---

> How do I check whether the remote repository has changed and I need to
> pull?

If you ask like that, just pull.

> How do I check whether the remote repository has finally done something and I want to pull?

Then you fetch and check and merge.

---

With single git commands:

```
$ git rev-list -1  master
9e1ff307c779ce1f0f810c7ecce3d95bbae40896
$ git rev-list -1  @
9e1ff307c779ce1f0f810c7ecce3d95bbae40896
```

This by itself does not say much, but suppose I know I did not commit anything, then:

```
$ git ls-remote origin HEAD master
60a9483534ed0d99090a2ee1d4bb0b8179195f51        HEAD
60a9483534ed0d99090a2ee1d4bb0b8179195f51        refs/heads/master
```

Will tell me that the remote has *changed*. It really has since last edit. kernel.org says `Age: 46 min.` about this last commit on master.

After `git fetch`:

```
$ git rev-list -1 master     
9e1ff307c779ce1f0f810c7ecce3d95bbae40896

$ git rev-list -1 FETCH_HEAD
60a9483534ed0d99090a2ee1d4bb0b8179195f51

$ git log --oneline ..FETCH_HEAD        
60a9483534ed (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge tag 'warning-fixes-20211005' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-fs
f6274b06e326 Merge tag 'linux-kselftest-fixes-5.15-rc5' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shuah/linux-kselftest
ef31499a87cf fscache: Remove an unused static variable
d9e3f82279bf fscache: Fix some kerneldoc warnings shown up by W=1
bc868036569e 9p: Fix a bunch of kerneldoc warnings shown up by W=1
dcb442b13364 afs: Fix kerneldoc warning shown up by W=1
c0b27c486970 nfs: Fix kerneldoc warning shown up by W=1
84b3e42564ac Merge tag 'media/v5.15-3' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mchehab/linux-media
b60be028fc1a Merge tag 'ovl-fixes-5.15-rc5' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mszeredi/vfs
df5c18838ea8 Merge tag 'mips-fixes_5.15_1' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mips/linux
206704a1fe0b media: atomisp: restore missing 'return' statement
740da9d7ca4e MIPS: Revert "add support for buggy MT7621S core detection"
1dc1eed46f9f ovl: fix IOCB_DIRECT if underlying fs doesn't support direct IO
2f9602870886 selftests: drivers/dma-buf: Fix implicit declaration warns
a295aef603e1 ovl: fix missing negative dentry check in ovl_rename()
```

Now I have all the information locally, but have not merged (yet). I also have all the objects downloaded. `git show HASH` or `git diff HASH` work.

In this case the merge is almost a no-op: fast-forward to the last commit and no extra (real) merge, let alone conflicts. This can be made sure by --ff-only:

```
$ git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD
Updating 9e1ff307c779..60a9483534ed
Fast-forward
...
...
```

So how can I know when to pull? As soon as these two hashes are/will, be different: `Updating 9e1ff307c779..60a9483534ed Fast-forward`. They can not be the same, that would be "nothing to update".

The newest reflog commits say the same:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline -g
60a9483534ed (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: merge 60a9483534ed0d99090a2ee1d4bb0b8179195f51: Fast-forward
9e1ff307c779 (tag: v5.15-rc4) HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
```

Looking at this, a new tag appearing is maybe the best trigger and also target in this case; that leads back to the `git ls-remote origin --tags PATTERN`.

---

...and don't tell me `git remote show` is *another* method:

> show          Gives some information about the remote .
>
> With -n option, the remote heads are not **queried first with git ls-remote** ; cached information is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many answers and multiple posts, and spending half a day trying various permutations, this is what I have come up with.

If you are on Windows, you may run this script in Windows using Git Bash provided by Git for Windows (installation or portable).

This script requires arguments

```
- local path e.g. /d/source/project1
- Git URL e.g. https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project1.git
- password

if a password should not be entered on the command line in plain text,
then modify the script to check if GITPASS is empty; do not
replace and let Git prompt for a password
```

The script will

```
- Find the current branch
- Get the SHA1 of the remote on that branch
- Get the SHA1 of the local on that branch
- Compare them.
```

If there is a change as printed by the script, then you may proceed to fetch or pull. The script may not be efficient, but it gets the job done for me.

Update - 2015-10-30: stderr to dev null to prevent printing the URL with the password to the console.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shell script to check if a Git pull is required.

LOCALPATH=$1
GITURL=$2
GITPASS=$3

cd $LOCALPATH
BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

echo
echo git url = $GITURL
echo branch = $BRANCH

# Bash replace - replace @ with :password@ in the GIT URL
GITURL2="${GITURL/@/:$GITPASS@}"
FOO="$(git ls-remote $GITURL2 -h $BRANCH 2> /dev/null)"
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
  echo cannot get remote status
  exit 2
fi
FOO_ARRAY=($FOO)
BAR=${FOO_ARRAY[0]}
echo [$BAR]

LOCALBAR="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
echo [$LOCALBAR]
echo

if [ "$BAR" == "$LOCALBAR" ]; then
  #read -t10 -n1 -r -p 'Press any key in the next ten seconds...' key
  echo No changes
  exit 0
else
  #read -t10 -n1 -r -p 'Press any key in the next ten seconds...' key
  #echo pressed $key
  echo There are changes between local and remote repositories.
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For the windows users who end up on this question looking for this, I've modified some of the answer into a powershell script. Tweak as necessary, save to a `.ps1` file and run on demand or scheduled if you like.

```
cd C:\<path to repo>
git remote update                           #update remote
$msg = git remote show origin               #capture status
$update = $msg -like '*local out of date*'
if($update.length -gt 0){                   #if local needs update
    Write-Host ('needs update')
    git pull
    git reset --hard origin/master
    Write-Host ('local updated')
} else {
    Write-Host ('no update needed')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, using git commands and simple string comparison:

```
BRANCH="develop"
git remote update

# Get the last 20 commits on the local branch
LOCAL_LOG=`git log --oneline -n20`

# Get the last commit on upstream
LAST_REV=`git rev-parse --short upstream/${BRANCH}`

# Check if the commit from upstream appears on the local commits    
if [[ ${LOCAL_LOG} =~ ${LAST_REV} ]]; then
  echo "[INFO] Local branch is up to date"
else
  echo "[WARNING] Local branch is out of date. Last revision ${LAST_REV}"
  git pull origin ${BRANCH} --no-edit
  git pull upstream ${BRANCH} --no-edit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a Windows Batch file to do this exact thing. I had a Ren'Py game where i want to check for a pull, then if there is one pull it and delete the cache (.rpyc) files, then run the app. You can adapt it for your own repo by removing the .rpyc and .exe steps.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set file="gitresult.log"
set maxbytesize=1

echo Checking for updates
git pull --dry-run > %file% 2>&1

rem check size
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    rem 0 bytes, empty file, up to date
    goto :end
) ELSE (
    rem 1+ bytes, there are changes
    goto :doupdate
)
exit /b

:doupdate
echo Grabbing updates
git pull
echo Deleting .rpyc files
del /Q /S /F *.rpyc

:end
ECHO Local repo is up to date
echo Operation complete, starting LR2
start gameExecutable.exe
exit
```

Answer (score -1):

Using simple regexp:

```
str=$(git status) 
if [[ $str =~ .*Your\ branch\ is\ behind.*by.*commits,\ and\ can\ be\ fast-forwarded ]]; then
    echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` "Needs pull"
else
    echo "Code is up to date"
fi
```

Comment: This will not work. git status is only a local check, and so it would only tell you if your branch is behind if you've already updated your remote defs.

Answer (score -5):

You can also find [a Phing script](https://github.com/drupol/Phingit) who does that now.

I needed a solution to update my production environments automatically and we're very happy thanks to this script that I'm sharing.

The script is written in XML and needs [Phing](https://www.phing.info/).