# Can't using pipe within "git.exe fetch origin" under Windows batch

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, pipe

I wrote a batch to check and deploy the rails app from github, the batch file see below. The problem is `git.exe fetch origin | find "remote: Counting Objects"` always returns `errorlevel 1`, even when we have new commits. I must terminate the Rails App first, because some files are locked (`*.jars`) and cause the `git pull` command to fail.

I search and found below topic, but even using `git.exe` instead of the `git.cmd`, the problem still exists.

- [Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed)
- [git bash : how to check if there's a new commit available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006759/git-bash-how-to-check-if-theres-a-new-commit-available)

I try to using a temp file to store `git.exe fetch origin` result, but if seems this command always print the result to the console.

Also:

```
git pull | find "Already up-to-date."
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
```

Works fine

```
    REM @echo off
    set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;D:\jruby-1.6.7\bin
    set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
    git.exe fetch origin | find "remote: Counting objects"
    if %errorlevel% == 0 taskkill /f /im:jruby.exe
    git pull | find "Already up-to-date."
    if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    REM 
      start cucumber.bat
      REM do something else when update
    )

    REM RAILS
    tasklist | find "jruby.exe"
    if %errorlevel%==1 (
     echo @rails s > rail.bat
     echo @exit >> rail.bat
     start cmd /c rail.bat
    )
    exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess I'd say it's breaking because the 'Counting objects' line shows a dynamic progress indicator, but don't quote me on that.

```
...
git fetch origin
git branch -a --no-merged |find "remotes/origin"
if %errorlevel% == 0 taskkill /f /im:jruby.exe
...
```

You might also want to limit it to just the current branch:

```
git branch -a --no-merged |find "remotes/origin/mybranch"
```

Comment: Thanks, git branch -a --no-merged | find "remotes/origin/HEAD -> master" works fine now.