# Get SHA1 of latest remote commit

Tags: git, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git bash : how to check if there’s a new commit available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006759/git-bash-how-to-check-if-theres-a-new-commit-available)

I am writing a script where I would like to compare the latest local commit to the latest upstream commit in order to tell the user there are commits to be pulled.

The latest local commit SHA is displayed with `git log | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`.

Is there an equivalent for printing the SHA1 of the latest upstream commit?

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git log | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: for check new commits in remotes I use this [git-prompt](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/git-prompt), this [lines make the job](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/git-prompt/blob/master/git-prompt.sh#L522-550)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Local head:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
```

Remote head:

```
$ git ls-remote <url> <refs>
```

> Displays references available in a remote repository along with the associated commit IDs.

Example:

```
$ cd ~/github/scrapy/scrapy
$ git rev-parse HEAD
9f003a73daec59a73c23a2214b1b8d15a4391a2f
$ git ls-remote git://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git HEAD
9f003a73daec59a73c23a2214b1b8d15a4391a2f
```

You can use diff to compare the output of the two:

```
$ diff <(git ls-remote git://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git HEAD) \
       <(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Comment: Interesting that the man page of `ls-remote` literally says "commit IDs" -- they're called SHAs in conventional git terminology. Must be some artifact from the early days ;)

Comment: +1 for simplicity... :->