# Automatic git pull in bash script

Tags: bash, git

Is it possible to know whether new commits have occured on remote git server using git commands inside bash script? I need it for automatic getting changes from remote host only when they exist.

Comment: If you have new commits from upstream, do you always want to pull them? If you do, you don't need to check anything.

Comment: After pulling I plan to start project build but I don't want ot start it when there was no changes in code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006759/git-bash-how-to-check-if-theres-a-new-commit-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute a `git fetch`. When there are no changes, nothing will happen, and when there are changes, they will be retrieved from the remote server. You could also use a `git pull`, in case changes are automatically merged.

Some more information:
https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/difference-between-git-fetch-git-pull

Comment: It was my fault. I thought that git fetch only writes data to local git database but fight now I rechecked it and found out that it also returns text but only one time per change in remote server. If I call it second time it returns nothing

Comment: @Hermann - I'm not sure if I'm following your comment.  If you call `fetch` a second time, it returns nothing because there are no changes, since your local was just updated by the first call.