# How to see if local git repo and remote repo are same commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repo, and I have a remote git repo. What is a simple command to see what commit the remote repo is, and what commit the local repo is, so I can simple see if I'm up to date?

This is going to be automated in a program, so I don't want lots of complicated stuff that I would have to parse. Preferably it would be cool to have both local & remote output the same text, with only the commit changing between the two. Any ideas?

Comment: This post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed seems be have what you need i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your remote repository is referred to by the remote `origin`, and you're interested in the branch `master`, you can do:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then compare the output of:

```
git rev-parse master
```

... and:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

If the object names that are output by those two commands are the same, then your `master` and the `master` in `origin` were the same at the point when the `git fetch origin` was run.

Comment: Any way to do this without actually downloading the repo?

Comment: Well, if you have a local repository (as you suggest in the question) then `git fetch` (with the common transports nowadays) is very efficient at only downloading the objects that you're missing.  However, if you really don't want to do that, then you could use `git ls-remote origin master`.

Answer (score 6):

#### A Programmatic Solution

If you want a programmatic solution, you can look at the commits stored in each head and compare them. For example:

```
remote=$(
    git ls-remote -h origin master |
    awk '{print $1}'
)
local=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

printf "Local : %s\nRemote: %s\n" $local $remote

if [[ $local == $remote ]]; then
    echo "Commits match."
else
    echo "Commits don't match."
fi
```

#### Sample Output

```
Local : 9e1b4dc286acb442f7f604be7916db660b9d70cd
Remote: 9e1b4dc286acb442f7f604be7916db660b9d70cd
Commits match.
```