# How to write a shell script that checks if git repository is up to date?

Tags: git, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
#gedit tidy plugin
init=false
SRC_DIR=~/repos

DIRECTORY="Gedit-Clientside-Plugin"
#making repos directory
if [ ! -d "$SRC_DIR" ]; then mkdir $SRC_DIR; fi



if [ ! -d "$SRC_DIR/$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    init=true
    cd $SRC_DIR && pwd && git clone git://github.com/trentrichardson/Gedit-Clientside-Plugin.git && cd $DIRECTORY
else
    cd $SRC_DIR/$DIRECTORY
fi
#below here is what I'm having trouble with
git pull 1>&1 | grep "Already up-to-date."

if [[ ! $? -eq 0 && ! $init ]]; then
    read -e -p "## Branch moved, build and install Gedit-Clientside-Plugin? [Y/n] " yn
    if [[ $yn == "y" || $yn == "Y" || $yn == "" ]] ; then
        if [ ! -d "/usr/share/gedit/plugins/clientside" ]; then
            sudo cp ~/repos/Gedit-Clientside-Plugin/clientside /usr/share/gedit/plugins/ -r
        else
            echo "Directory already exists."
        fi
    fi
fi
```

The above code is something I have edited from a script I have found on stackoverflow to install Emacs from git repository. What I want this script to do is to install any programs from git repos, and update them if an update is necessary. Of course I will have to provide the steps to install it. In this script's case it just needs to copy the `clientside` directory to `/usr/share/gedit/plugins/` directory.

I do not need any help with how to install any script but what I need is how to check if repository is up to date and go from there.

Right now what I don't understand is this part:

```
git pull 1>&1 | grep "Already up-to-date."

    if [[ ! $? -eq 0 && ! $init ]]; then
.....
    fi
```

When I run `git pull 1>&1 | grep "Already up-to-date." && $?` in terminal the output is `Already up-to-date. 0`. So I understand that this is the part that checks for updates however the next part doesn't execute (the if statement)- which is the part that copies the directory to gedit plugin directory. I do not understand what `1>$1` means or what `$?` means. Therefore I could not solve the problem... And what I do not understand is why it thinks that `Branch is moved` when it is not up to date (I'm just assuming that it says that when `git pull` doesn't return `0` in the if statement).

I'm sure it has a simple solution and the answer will be both educating for bash and git. I appreciate all the help.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: `1>&1` is weird, I have no clue; it redirects stdout to stdout. You usually see it in `2>&1` form, which redirects stderr (2) to stdout (1). `$?` is last exit code; it will be `0` if `grep` matched something, non-`0` if it failed to match (or experienced another error, like accessing non-existent file).

Comment: So I'm guessing that `1>&1` is totally pointless... wouldn't make a difference if it was there or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would rather use the solution of "[git: check if pull needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791408/6309)":

```
git fetch origin
reslog=$(git log HEAD..origin/master --oneline)
if [[ "${reslog}" != "" ]] ; then
  git merge origin/master # completing the pull
  ...
```

Answer (score 7):

As already noticed by Vonc, this question overlaps "[git: check if pull needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791408/6309)".

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791408/6309) I suggested the following one-line script that takes the SHA1 of your last commited version and compares it to the one of the remote origin

```
[ `git log --pretty=%H ...refs/heads/master^` = `git ls-remote origin
-h refs/heads/master |cut -f1` ] && echo "up to date" || echo "not up to date"
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to edit Claudio's answer

```
[ "`git log --pretty=%H ...refs/heads/master^ | head -n 1`" = "`git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master |cut -f1`" ] && echo "up to date" || echo "not up to date"
```

Comment: thanks for this! i took this simple one-liner and throw it into some small check_mk monitoring script: https://github.com/MaxWinterstein/check_git_pullstatus