# What to do when I have message : as the Component overload no longer exists

Tags: git, github

I updated from master to local source code rep, based on this link: [git: check if pull needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/git-check-if-pull-needed), and there was updated I needed to pull to my rep
so I did using this :

```
git pull remote master
```

but now if I do :

```
git show-branch *master
```

I'm getting :

```
$ git show-branch *master
* [master] Change references to Component::OnSetAttribute() to Serializable::OnSetAttribute() as the Component overload no longer exists.
 ! [refs/remotes/origin/master] Change references to Component::OnSetAttribute() to Serializable::OnSetAttribute() as the Component overload no longer exists.
--
*+ [master] Change references to Component::OnSetAttribute() to Serializable::OnSetAttribute() as the Component overload no longer exists.
```

what does it means :`Component overload no longer exists`
and what should I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `git show *master` it attempts to visualise the commit graph for all the branches in your repository that end with "master". The message that you refer to is simply the commit message - author's description of the changes.

Maybe this fact will become clearer if you visualise the commit graph for the master branch only, for instance as follows,

```
$ git log --oneline --graph master
```