# How is a merge-base done in JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm looking at the [JGit Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/documentation/), currently at version *3.5.1.201410131835-r*, and I cannot find the equivalent of [git-merge-base](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base).

I would like to determine if a branch is up-to-date, behind, ahead, or diverged, as shown in [git: check if pull needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/231573).

What is the most concise way in JGit to find as good common ancestors as possible for a merge?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `RevFilter.MERGE_BASE` for that:

```
RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.MERGE_BASE);
walk.markStart(commit1);
walk.markStart(commit2);
RevCommit mergeBase = walk.next();
```

Also note that there is [BranchTrackingStatus](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/3.5.1.201410131835-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/BranchTrackingStatus.html) if all you are interested in is ahead/behind count of a branch compared to its remote-tracking branch.

Per https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1091725/, you may need to re-parse the commits with `walk.parseCommit()`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to adding "--fork-point" because I'm not getting the same results as "git merge-base --fork-point"?

Comment: @PeterKahn: Does this work?: https://gist.github.com/robinst/997da20d09a82d85a3e9 (I'm pretty sure it can be done more efficiently, so use with care)

Comment: @robinst thanks. I'll try that.  I found this to work but it's a little kludgy and I'm not sure how we'll it will work if there are merges between sibling or cousin branches.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35353202/9950

Comment: Can it handle an octopus merge-base?  Do you just keep adding markStart() calls?

Comment: FYI make sure you're using `walk.parseCommit()` to ensure `commit1.parents` and `commit2.parents` aren't missing. I spent a good hour trying to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with JGit using BranchTrackingStatus:

```
public enum TrackingStatus {
    SAME, BEHIND, AHEAD, DIVERGED
}

public TrackingStatus getTrackingStatus() throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    Repository userRepo = new FileRepository(<path_to_.git_file>);
    Git git = new Git(userRepo);
    git.fetch().call();
    BranchTrackingStatus bts = BranchTrackingStatus.of(git.getRepository(),
                                                       git.getRepository().getBranch());
    int aheadCount = bts.getAheadCount();
    int behindCount = bts.getBehindCount();
    if (aheadCount == 0 && behindCount == 0) {
        return TrackingStatus.SAME;
    } else if (aheadCount > 0 && behindCount == 0) {
        return TrackingStatus.AHEAD;
    } else if (aheadCount == 0 && behindCount > 0) {
        return TrackingStatus.BEHIND;
    } else {
        return TrackingStatus.DIVERGED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jgit has this:

```
RevCommit org.eclipse.jgit.merge.Merger.getBaseCommit(RevCommit a, RevCommit b) throws IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException
```

take a try

Answer (score 0):

This method is `protected`, so cannot be used directly:

`protected RevCommit getBaseCommit(RevCommit a, RevCommit b) throws IncorrectObjectTypeException, IOException`