# Detect which git repositories were updated past x weeks?

Tags: git, bash, shell, zsh

I have a set of git repositories, say 10, in a directory. Would like to have a quick glance at which of them were recently updated, in last say 2 weeks (this will be of course configurable). How to do it?

The update means commit has been made. In other words it's not about pull, it's about: what repositories have fresh commits, locally. Is there some nice method for this?

Comment: What means updated? Does it mean a commit has been made during that time in an arbitrary branch? What have you tried already?

Comment: See: [Check if pull needed in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3258243/3776858)

Comment: @hek2mgl: why should I try anything? Why did you down vote, it was you didn't you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the below into a script file, e.g. `updateCheck.sh`:

```
for directory in `ls -d */`; do
    pushd $directory >/dev/null
    if [ -d ".git" ]; then
        if [[ `git log -1 --all --since=$1` ]];
        then
          echo $directory
        fi
    fi
    popd >/dev/null
done
```

Run it in the directory that contains all of the repos, and pass as an argument to the script how far back you want to check for updates, e.g. `updateCheck.sh 2.weeks`, `updateCheck.sh 5.days`, etc.

Comment: Nice option to this, --max-count=1, correct? Why --all?

Comment: @ManaCode - the `--all` checks all branches. Without it, only the currently checked out branch in each repo will be checked. And you are correct about the max count thing; I have edited the answer accordingly.