# git status vs git status -u vs git status -uno

Tags: git

I am slightly confused by the documentation. Kindly, correct me.

`git status`
- show the current local working directory status

`git status -u`
- show untracked files (also local)

`git status -uno`
- show no untracked files (also local) ??

I don't understand the last two. Any examples? Also, how do we show whether there are any changes remotely? So that I can decide whether to pull or not. I thought the last command helped me do that.. but apparently not anymore.

Comment: You can always `git fetch`, and then decide whether to merge or not. (pull = fetch + merge)

Comment: Your "also" deserves to be a separate question, but is already answered elsewhere, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-u` or `--untracked-files=` flag to `git status` takes an additional parameter that is one of three values:

- `no`: do not show untracked files
- `normal`: show untracked files and directories
- `all`: a more-verbose variant of `normal`

Omitting the additional word means the same as using `-unormal` (or `--untracked-files=normal`).  So `normal` is the default, while `no` suppresses them entirely.

The additional verbosity with `all` simply takes the form of enumerating every file *within* an untracked directory:

```
$ git status
...
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    weeble/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git status -uall
...
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    weeble/file1
    weeble/file2
```

Normally, `-u` (aka `-unormal`) has no effect on `git status`.  However, if you change your defaults (by, e.g., setting `status.showUntrackedFiles` to `no`), `-u` will make `git status` display untracked files, i.e., override your modified default.

Comment: I just realized that `git status -u no` doesn't give an error, but doesn't do what I expected it to do (namely what `git status -uno` does. You answer solved the mystery ;-)