# I am using Node.js, express, Angular, Postgresql on Windows. What is the best way to mirror and code updates between servers?

Tags: node.js, express, mirroring

I am using Node.js, express, Angular, Postgresql on Windows. What is the best way to mirror and code updates between servers? I have read about rsync. Any other ones out there for the most recent js technologies?

Comment: Why not just use a private github repository and have each server pull releases from there?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a possible solution. Questions: can git detect this automatically to pull whenever there is a new push?

Comment: I think you have to poll the repository on some interval: [Check if pull needed in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

The delivery/deployment/backup of your code is agnostic to the code itself. Therefore a deployment method for "recent js technologies" is nonsensical. I suggest you familiarize yourself with Git as it is the industry standard. It acts a little bit like Dropbox for your code.

Check out this tutorial to quickly get a sense of what git is. https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

After that, read the official doc to understand how it works under the hood, it'll be easier to deal with issues later if you understand the ins and outs of the tech. https://git-scm.com/doc