# How to check if locally downloaded git repository was updated? And how to update it?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I learned how to download a Git repository without a history (to save disk space and Internet traffic). I created file `git-no-history.bat` with this content:

```
git clone --depth 1 %1
```

Now I need to create files `git-check.bat` (check if my version is the last one) and `git-update.bat` (get to the last version). What should I write here?

If possible, also describe how to do these three operations in [TortoiseGit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit).

No Linux Bash please; I have zero experience with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Comment: @WendingPeng i don't understand linux bash, sorry

Comment: @puppon-su, the accepted answer on that question contains very little bash. Please read it and try to understand what it is saying, then apply your learning to your own situation.

Answer (score 0):

`git-check.bat`:

```
@echo off

git fetch origin
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto end



rem #get number of new commits
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('git rev-list HEAD...origin/master --count') DO set numofupdates=%%i

if [%numofupdates%]==[0] goto nothing_new


rem #get list of new commits
git log HEAD..origin/master --oneline


set ask=
set /p ask=Update? (y/n)
if not [%ask%]==[y] goto nah

echo Updating...
git merge origin
echo Done!
goto end

:nah
echo Nah...
goto end

:nothing_new
echo Nothing new
goto end

:end

rem Looks like `git pull` is the same as `git fetch origin` plus `git merge origin`.
```

I'll live without `git-update.bat`, it will require doing `git fetch origin` twice. Maybe there is a way to get time of last fetch, but that's too complex for bat.