# Warning dialog when git sync is available?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

If I open a project in VS Code, or I change the branch I'm working on, a check happens to see if `git pull` or `git push` (git sync) for that branch is possible. If so, it is shown in the lower left corner:

[image]

However, I always forget to check this, so I start coding and get into conflicts when merging.

Is there an option in VS Code (or an extension) to give a popup warning when a git sync is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set a pre-commit hook which would check if your local repo is in sync.

See for instance "[Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/6309)".
It will be used with Git or Git in Visual Studio Code.

If your repo is not "in sync" with its remote counter-part (pull or push are possible), then the commit is refused.

That would force you to pull first.

Combine that "[Can “git pull” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)":

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

And your pull will automatically stash for you your work in progress, fetch, rebase your current commits on top of the updated branch, and re-apply your work in progress.
Then you can do a `git commit`.