# How to check whether my collaborator update the remote or not in git?

Tags: git

I have a git repository in my local and also in github. I have also a collaborator(my partner) in that github repository. I have added some new file in my local and push those in the remote by `git push origin master` and the updates are shown in github repo.

Now, my partner try to know whether any update in remote using `git fetch` but results nothing although the remote is updated with new files.

What is the exact command to know this and add those in local?

Comment: u can use git pull to get the updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the git fetch is done from a local repo which has the same remote URL as your GitHub repo:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote -v
```

Then check which branch has actually been updated with:

```
git branch -avv
```

You will see the remote branches

Comment: git branch -avv shows `$ git branch -avv\\
* master                02ce9f9 [origin/master: behind 1] update DDL.sql\\
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master 15f4296 add Image directory`

Comment: @moon Then a git pull will update master (it will fetch and merge)

Comment: @moon Yes, because your local master is tracking origin/master.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258243/6648243) accepted answer:

1. `git remote update` to update your refs
2. `git status -uno` will give the status of the branch you are tracking