# Check if git submodule has been updated on remote

Tags: git, cmake

I want to add a check to my cmake script that checks if the head of the remote submodule repository has been updated. Up until now I just ran `git submodule update --init --recursive` in the script, however this could end up in unexpected changes if the remote submodule is updated. 
Is there a nice way to check if the remote head is a few commits in front of the local submodule's head without changing the state of the local submodule?

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/7976758 I'd do something like this:

```
git submodule foreach git remote update
git submodule foreach git --no-pager diff origin/master master
```

If submodules use different branches the script needs to take that into account.