# How to avoid doing git flow release when local master is behind remote master

Tags: git, git-flow

More than once, we've done a `git flow release 1.23` on a release branch, only to discover that `master` was behind `origin/master`, and now the new `master` and `origin/master` have now diverged.

I've created a [feature request](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/issues/378) to avoid this on git-flow, but apart from manually checking, is there any way to avoid finishing a release when the local master is behind the remote master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering [`git flow release`](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#release) starts a release branch from *develop*, not `master`, that should not make `master` diverge from `origin/master`.

But assuming it would, you might consider writing a [client `pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) which would reject any new commit if it [detects that `master` and `origin/master` don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258243/6309).