# How do I check if there are new commits in another branch without switching branches?

Tags: git, repository, fetch, branch, checkout

The case is pretty simple, I work in branchA and wish to see if there new commits in branchB. And branchA and branchB are completelly different, separated branches, I need neither merge nor pull anything, just to find out if it has new commits or it doesn't. I can pretty simple do it with source tree git client, but I wish to find out how do I check it with git console.

git fetch origin gives me no information about it:

```
git fetch origin branchB
From https://github.com/user_name/repo_name
 * branch            offline-mode -> FETCH_HEAD
```

How do I check if there are new commits in another branch without switching branches?

Comment: After fetching, just run `gitk --all` or `git log --graph --all --oneline --decorate`.

Comment: I believe that when doing `git fetch` the output will show you whether `branchB` were updated or not.  In any case, if you want to update `branchA` with `branchB`, you can always just try something like rebasing.  If no new commits have come in, nothing would happen anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+different+branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing `git fetch` to update your local branches, you can see the state of all your branches with `git branch -vv`.  This will list all of your branches along with the remote branch that they are tracked to.  It will also say if the branch is ahead or behind the remote.