# How to improve the time to prepare my repo for a jenkins build task?

Tags: git, jenkins, optimization, git-submodules, git-reset

I have a bitbucket repo where I do all my work. It has a development branch that I branch from to add any features or fix any bugs. When I do a pull request to merge to develop branch I trigger a jenkins build:

The build goes through some steps, and While going through the log I found out that most of the time is wasted doing these 3 git commands:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
git submodule foreach --recursive "git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -xffd"
```

The submodules in my repo dont change that often, and its the responsibility of other team members, and I dont know when they change anything in them.

Is there away to avoid these 2 commands by checking if the submodules have no changes? is so go to the next submodule and check?

I tried to use  "https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278427/7976758" but this works for a main repo, not sure how to write a script that goes in the submodule and run the same script.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try to disable the recursive update of submodules at your job config

Comment: But this means that I will not catch any updates in the sub-modules if any happens later on. and I want to catch those updates if they happens automatically