# How to check if git pull is successful from Process.ExitCode

Tags: c#, git, process, git-pull, exit-code

I am calling `git pull` using `ProcessInfo`

I am checking `ExitCode` for all the commands for there success.

So if `ExitCode` is 0 the command ran successfully if not there is some error.

All works fine, the problem occurs when it tries to do a `git pull` and the repository is already up to date.
In that case git considers it a fail and so returns `ExitCode=1`, but for me it is a success, it is just that there was nothing to be pulled.

Is there any way I can check the success of pull command?

I have one approach in mind that if I can somehow run a command to check if there is anything to be pulled, if that command returns true then I will do a pull else won't

This post gives the option to check if anything is there to be pulled
[Check if pull needed in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git)

Can somebody help if there is direct way to handle pull alone or what should I check before pull?

Comment: Why not check the output?

Comment: @John - Output is a string. I do not find it a right way to check the string value.

Comment: Perhaps your git repository has an API you can invoke instead of using the command line. As the result of the git pull is written to standard out, the only way to read in the response is, well... as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `git pull` in scripts.

Git generally divides its commands into *plumbing commands*, which are *intended* to be used from scripts, and *porcelain commands*, which are intended to be run by humans.  A plumbing command behaves in predictable ways and has reliable exit codes, and either produces, or has options to produce, machine-readable output when appropriate.  A porcelain command does not.  A few commands, such as `git status`, can operate either way: `git status --porcelain=v2` runs `git status` in a "plumbing way".<sup>1</sup>  Porcelain commands also often obey specific user configuration controls, so that there is no guarantee that two different users running the same command get the same behavior.

The `git pull` command is strictly porcelain, not plumbing.

The underlying plumbing command to be used here is `git fetch`.  Having run `git fetch` (perhaps with additional options), you can parse its output, which is reasonably reliable, or use `git rev-parse`—another plumbing command—to see new values for various references.

If your script really needs to invoke `git merge` or `git rebase`, you can do that at this point, but note that these commands are meant as porcelain and can "stop in the middle" (with merge conflicts that a user must resolve).  But it is at least simpler to decode what has happened in these cases, as both `git merge` and `git rebase` do have reliable exit status.

---

<sup>1</sup>It has always baffled me why this option is spelled `--porcelain` instead of `--plumbing`.

Answer (score 0):

> Having run `git fetch` (perhaps with additional options),

Warning: if you are using `--prune` as an additional option, do use Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)

When "[`git fetch --prune`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c73d46b3a8450f499df84682be73a13b6578d82c/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L129)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune))</sup> failed to prune the refs it wanted to prune, the command issued error messages but exited with exit status 0, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit c9e04d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e04d905edb5487c43b03304704e8d1248f9ac0) (31 Jan 2022) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c73d46b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c73d46b3a8450f499df84682be73a13b6578d82c), 11 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch --prune`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e04d905edb5487c43b03304704e8d1248f9ac0): exit with error if pruning fails
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Thomas Gummerer</sup>

> When pruning refs fails, we print an error to stderr, but still exit 0 from '[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c9e04d905edb5487c43b03304704e8d1248f9ac0/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>.
> Since this is a genuine error, fetch should be exiting with some non-zero exit code.
> Make it so.
>
> The `--prune` option was introduced in [f360d84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f360d844de4b752b4cba2343b95592ae4d55d09a) ("`builtin-fetch`: [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f360d844de4b752b4cba2343b95592ae4d55d09a/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> `--prune` option", 2009-11-10, Git v1.6.6-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65c042d44dc843021f1410f1219104681fdd3469)).
> Unfortunately it's unclear from that commit whether ignoring the exit code was an oversight or intentional, but it feels like an oversight.