# gitlab - check if forked repository needs to be synced with main repo

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have main repository and a forked repository.

I'm writing a gitlab-ci pipeline for the forked repository, and wanted to know if there's a way to check if the repository is synced with the main?

I don't want to pull changes, just check if there are changes to pull.
So in case the forked is not synced I will fail the job.

I'm aware of `git remote` commands or `git status -uno` but did not find anything that fits.

Please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258243/7976758

Comment: (1) add a remote for the other repository; (2) run `git fetch` or `git ls-remote` using the added remote; (3) compare hash IDs to see if you're in sync. This gets you your answer about whether you're in sync.