# How To Find Out If A File In Git Has Changed In Remote Branch

Tags: git

I would like to be able to tell if a particular file which I have in my local git branch, has been updated on the remote branch since my last update.

Is there something I can do on the command line to see if this file has been changed?

Comment: A good answer to a very similar (identical?) question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19558846/758446

Comment: Thanks for that, in my case I need to see if a particular file has changed on the remote, not whether the remote branch has changed at all.  Do you know of a way I could find out which files changed?

Comment: The answer BlackVegetable pointed you at was has accepted solution "git fetch origin" then "git diff origin/master". The diff would include your file if it has changed. That would be equivalent to an svn diff if you were using svn. I don't understand your problem with that solution.

Comment: @Sammy So when I do "git diff origin/master" it gives me an error that says "fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."  am I not supposed to literally put "origin/master" there, I'm pretty new when it comes to git.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The branch you are comparing two goes in the latter half of that string.  So if the branch you are comparing to is named "foo" you would try `git fetch origin && git diff origin/foo`.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know.  Thanks for putting up with my ignorance to git!

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question as a duplicate.  I don't mean any offense to you at all of course. I just want people in a similar situation to be directed toward that answer that basically resolved your question. I'm glad to help.