# Java monitor GitHub repository

Tags: java, git, github

I want to create a Java application that monitors a GitHub repository, pulls changes to the machine it is running on and triggers a method when something in the repo has changed.

```
while(true)
{
    if(new commits on the remote github repo)
    {
        pullChanges();
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I am currently using [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) and regularly deleting the local repository to clone a new one and compare the combined file size to check if anything has changed. This is incredibly hacky and not reliable (if a commit just changes a letter, the file sizes would be the same)

Comment: you should be able to get the commit log from the repository using jgit and if the hash changes pull the changes.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java) is a sample for retrieving the commit log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to clone the repository when the java application starts, after that I created a seperate thread that pulls new commits from the repository every 30 seconds and checks if something has changed with the 'FetchResult' returned from the Java method.

These helped me:

[Cloning a repo](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepositoryWithAuthentication.java)

[Pulling commits](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/unfinished/PullFromRemoteRepository.java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitHub Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

> Webhooks allow you to build or set up integrations which subscribe to certain events on GitHub.com. When one of those events is triggered, we'll send a HTTP POST payload to the webhook's configured URL. Webhooks can be used to update an external issue tracker, trigger CI builds, update a backup mirror, or even deploy to your production server. You're only limited by your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Your method to get a diff between your local copy and the remote is too tricky to be reliable.

See this post: [How to check for changes on remote (origin) Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514270/how-to-check-for-changes-on-remote-origin-git-repository)