# Why does `git st` say I am up-to-date, but I am not?

Tags: git

When I do a `git st` in a repository I get the message:

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
```

But then when I do a `git pull` a lot of commits are downloaded.

But I thought the current checkout/working directory is up-to-date with `origin`?

Do I understand something wrong here?

Comment: `git st` is not a git(1) command. Did you mean `git status`?

Comment: If you're unsure: `git config --list | grep alias.st`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does git status show branch is up-to-date when changes exist upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828404/why-does-git-status-show-branch-is-up-to-date-when-changes-exist-upstream)

Answer (score 3):

`git status` displays the *working tree* status,  i.e.

> what you would commit by running `git commit` [...] and what you could commit by running `git add` before running `git commit`

It has nothing to do with any *remote* status.

See [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2514270/14015737) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258243/14015737) discuss checking for remote changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. As for the docs, these contain names like `working tree`, `index file`, `HEAD`, `tracked`. Is there some documentation available in some simple English?

Comment: There are some resources that attempt to explain this without diving in deep. This [simple guide](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) tries to explain the concepts you asked about in a few sentences. However, it is worth spending a bit of time getting a bit deeper into the general concept. One important aspect is that `git` is a _distributed_ version control system, that does not need any remote repository at all.

Comment: @Alex https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary could help.

Answer (score 2):

`origin/main` is what git calls a "tracking branch". This is a local copy of a branch in another repository (called a remote). The key here is that this local copy is only updated with commands like `git fetch` or `git pull`. When you run `git status`, it compares your local branch `main` with the tracking branch `origin/main`. It does NOT query the remote to find out what its `main` branch is like.

Answer (score 2):

`git status` does not reach out to the remote repository to see what is there. It only looks at what is already cached locally in `refs/remotes/origin/main` a.k.a. `origin/main`.

To see whether the repository is up to date with the remote, the tools to use *are* `git fetch` and `git pull`.

Comment: I have no idea what `refs/remotes/...` mean

Comment: When we talk about the (local) branch `main`, then we talk about a "ref" whose full name is actually `refs/heads/main`. All (local) branches live under the `refs/heads` hierarchy. All remote-tracking branches live under the hierarchy `refs/remotes`. These are managed by `git fetch` (and `git pull`). There is usually a remote repository called `origin`, therefore, its remote tracking branches are in the hierarchy `refs/remotes/origin`, for example `refs/remotes/origin/main`, which can be referred to in abbreviated  form with `origin/main`.